# Can I use pavers as a basement floor in an 1830s farm house?

Tags: basement, floor, brick

I have an 1830s New England farm house with a dirt floor basement. I have put down a plastic vapor barrier and put down crushed stone over it. This alone dried the house out considerably, and during the winter, the core of the house is actually a little bit warmer.

I have a lot of concrete brick pavers. So my question would be if I were to level off the crushed stone and put down brick pavers, would this be a suitable substitute for a floor in my basement? Thanks for any input.

Comment: That would be up to you. Making it a matter of opinion, and thus not really suitable here. Take the [tour].

Comment: It will be a floor, not a substitute.  Poured concrete floors are just the most common type.  If you have enough "free" pavers, go for it.

Comment: OBTW - Old New England farmhouse with basement - run a radon test if you haven't already done that.

Comment: It might be quite suitable for your purposes, but it might not be suitable for someone else... Would it _work_ as a basement floor? Sure, if it's suitable for _your_ purposes...

Answer (score 1):

"Suitable" is subjective, and not for us to decide. Whether that sort of floor is appropriate for your usage is your call.

That said, I think what you're asking is whether there would be any *problems* in doing so. There wouldn't. It's essentially the same as a solid slab, practically speaking.

Be aware that the gravel and pressure may perforate your plastic sheeting. Consider coarse sand instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your home has a dirt floor in the basement so your foundation is either in the form of footers or pile caps. Using pavers as a floor will structurally work. Whether it works for you long term is another story.